# RoR - Retrieve a data from controller and display using AJAX

Tags: ruby, ajax

I have a controller that assign to pass a value to ajax but when in execution no value are printed, here are my code:

**:User Controller**

```
  def search_name
    @nama = params[:name] //Get a value from user input
    @user = User.select(:name).where(['name = ?', params[@nama]]).all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {render :json => @user}
      format.html { render :json => @user}
    end
  end
```

**:my.js**

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/users/search_name/',         
        type:'get',
        data:{
        name:nama           
        },
        dataType:'json',

        success:function(puser){            

        var userName = '';
        for(x in puser){
               userName += 'Name here"'+ puser[x]['user']['name'] +'";

                 }
                 $('.search-result').html(userName);
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

to debug this js issue, please use your browser to visit:     /users/search_name  , to see what the result is.

Comment: i have getting error 500, mean that i have a problem with my controller right?

Comment: sure, of course.  check the error message by `tail log/production.log -n 333` if you are using production mode.